# Auto refresh a webpage every N minutes

Tags: applications, browser

Does anyone know any way that I can refresh a webpage every N minutes?

I am running Kiosk browser with fullscreen, I need to have something that can refresh the page every N minutes. The Kiosk browser I am using has no such function built in.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you use javascript with an interval to refresh your content.

Comment: Because I dont have control of page coding.

Answer (score 2):

I'd personally use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) for something like this. The process would be quite simple:

- New Trigger -> Time
- Give a time window (workday 7:00 am to 5:00 pm)
- Check "Repeat:" every **xx** and change to Minutes
- New Task -> Name (something like "Open Webpage")
- New Action -> Net -> Browse URL
- Type in URL

That Task should cause the device to relaunch the webpage every **xx** minutes through the default browser, so we're assuming that's set to your Kiosk browser.

Comment: Found my own solution, updated.

Comment: Add it as an answer and mark it as the solution so others can find your answer as well!

Answer (score 1):

Just insert this code anywhere in your kiosk browser content to refresh your web app every one minute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () { location.reload(true); }, 60000);
</script>
```

Comment: how to setup "location" in your script? and setup to every one minute?

Comment: @RootLoop, I edited my answer for one minute...

Comment: Found my own solution, updated.

Answer (score 1):

I found my own solution and it is working good.

Need to use "Dolphin" browser with "Tab Reload" add-ons

It can be found in google play store.